# linux raid0 array size

Tags: linux, raid0

I made linux raid0 with 4 disks (1TB each).
mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md0  shows Array Size to be 4TB.
But when I mount this shared folder in a windows PC, it says that it has 105 GB size.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean 4TB? And, also how are you mounting this on a Windows PC?

Comment: oops yes corrected.

Comment: I use SAMBA server

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing "105 GB *Used*"? Can you add a screenshot of what you are seeing, or explain the steps you're taking to access the shared volume from the Windows client?

Answer (score 0):

A Windows client accessing a share via "[CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)" should not have a problem w/ the size.
However, the "Total", "Free" and "Used" sizes reported by the Windows client may not reflect reality for a number of reasons (the server doesn't "refresh" the remote volume at the same rate as a local volume).